# Python Game Challenge - First to Five

Tags: python, game

I have nearly one year of experience with C++, and it's been a month that I have been diving into Python. I came across this python game challenge on the internet called First to Five.

> The rules are the following: There are two players. Each player writes
>   a number. It can be any integer 1 or
>   greater. The players reveal their numbers. Whoever chose the lower
>   number gets 1 point, unless the lower number is lower by only 1, then
>   the player with the higher number gets 2 points. If they both chose
>   the same number, neither player gets a point. This repeats, and the
>   game ends when one player has 5 points.

I really like to use OOP, most of my practices use it, and I would love to know a little bit about your opinions and thoughts about this code. What/How can I improve? Is it good? Am I using conventions and good practices?

```
class Game:
    game_win_point = 5;

    def __init__(self):
        self.victory = False;
        self.winner = "";
        self.player1 = Player();
        self.player2 = Player();

    def gatherInformation(self):
        """ Gathers information about both players playing the game before the game starts. """
        self.player1.setName(input("What's the name of player 1? >> "));
        self.player2.setName(input("What's the name of player 2? >> "));

    def check_number_input(self):
        """ Checks if both players entered valid input. """
        self.check_input(self.player1);
        self.check_input(self.player2);

    def check_input(self, player):
        """ Checks if 'player' entered a valid input. """
        try:
            player.setCurrentNumber(int(input("{}'s number: >> ".format(player.name))));
            if player.current_number <= 0:
                raise ValueError;
        except ValueError:
            while not isinstance(player.current_number, int) or player.current_number <= 0:
                print("{}, you have to input an integer greater than one!".format(player.name));
                try:
                    player.setCurrentNumber(int(input("{}'s number: >> ".format(player.name))));
                except ValueError:
                    player.setCurrentNumber(-1);

    def update_game_score(self):
        """ Updates the game score every round. """
        if self.player1.current_number == self.player2.current_number:
            # The numbers are the same.
            print("The numbers are the same and nobody gets a point! The score is: {}: {} points VS {}: {} points".format(p1.name, p1.score, p2.name, p2.score));
        else:
            # The numbers are diferent.
            greatest_number = max(self.player1.current_number, self.player2.current_number);
            self.who_scores(greatest_number, self.player1, self.player2);
            self.who_scores(greatest_number, self.player2, self.player1);

    def who_scores(self, greatest_number, ps, pl):
        """
        'greatest_number' stands for the maximum number inputted by player 1 and 2.
        'ps' stands for 'possible scorer' and it is the player who is supposed to get a score.
        'pl' stands for 'possible loser' and it is the player who is NOT supposed to get a score.
        Decides who scores a point.
        """
        if (greatest_number == ps.current_number):

            if pl.current_number == (ps.current_number - 1):
                # Then, 'possible_scorer' scores, because the 'possible_loser.current_number' is smaller by just 1.
                ps.goal(point=2);
            else:
                # Then, 'possible_loser' scores, because the 'possible_loser.current_number' is the smallest.
                pl.goal();

    def check_winner(self):
        """ Checks if there's a game winner. """
        if self.player1.score >= self.game_win_point:
            self.setVictory(True);
            self.setWinner(self.player1);

        if self.player2.score >= self.game_win_point:
            self.setVictory(True);
            self.setWinner(self.player2);

    def setVictory(self, victory):
        """ Sets the game victory variable to True if one of the players reach 5
        or more points. Otherwise, it remains False."""
        self.victory = victory;

    def setWinner(self, winner):
        """ Sets the specified winner player by the 'winner' attribute. """
        self.winner = winner;

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0;
        self.name = "no_name";
        self.current_number = -1;

    def setScore(self, score):
        """ Setter/Mutator to set a player's score. """
        self.score = score;

    def setName(self, name):
        """ Setter/Mutator to set a player's name. """
        self.name = name;

    def setCurrentNumber(self, current_number):
        """ Setter/Mutator to set a player's current inputted number. """
        self.current_number = current_number;

    def goal(self, point=1):
        """ Increases this player's score. """
        self.score += point;

def main():

    print("Welcome to the game! This game was made for two players.");
    game = Game();

    game.gatherInformation();

    while not game.victory:

        # Getting input. If it is not a correct input, let's loop while the user gives uses a proper one.
        game.check_number_input();
        print("{} typed {}, and {} typed {}".format(game.player1.name, game.player1.current_number, game.player2.name, game.player2.current_number));

        # Checking who earns a points, if there's someone.
        game.update_game_score();

        # Displaying the results of this round.
        print("Results: {}: {} points VS {}: {} points.".format(game.player1.name, game.player1.score, game.player2.name, game.player2.score));

        # Checking if there is a winner.
        game.check_winner();

    print("Congratulations, {}! You're the winner.".format(game.winner.name));

if __name__ == "__main__": main();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. In Python, there's no need to use a semi-colon to end a statement.
2. Similarly, there's no need to put parentheses around the condition of an `if` statement.
3. The docstrings on the methods are good, but there should also be docstrings on the classes.
4. There's a bug in `Game.update_game_score`. If both players enter the same number, there's a `NameError` because the code uses `p1` and `p2` instead of `self.player1` and `self.player2`.
5. The message "you have to input an integer greater than one" isn't right: you can also enter the number 1.
6. The `Game.check_input` method uses the methods and attributes of a single `Player` object. This suggests that it should be a method on the `Player` class.
7. The `check_input` method is misleadingly named, because it gets the input as well as checking it.
8. Instead of a separate `gatherInformation` function, it would make sense to gather the player's name in `Player.__init__`.
9. There's a lot of repeated code of the form:

   ```
   do_something(self.player1)
   do_something(self.player2)
   ```

   This repetition can be avoided by putting the two players into a list, and iterating over the list:

   ```
   for player in self.players:
       do_something(player)
   ```
10. In Python, we don't generally bother with setters or mutators, we just update the appropriate attribute. So instead of:

    ```
    self.setVictory(True)
    ```

    we'd just write:

    ```
    self.victory = True
    ```

    and avoid the need for a `setVictory` method. The reason is that if we later need to do something clever whenever an attribute is set, we can do that using the [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator. We don't have to plan it in advance by writing getters and setters.

    (But later on we'll see that we don't even need a `victory` attribute.)
11. The logic in `check_input` is quite complex and repetitive. It could be simplified so that there is just one call to `input`, and just one `try: ... except:`. If you follow my suggestion of making this a method on the `Player` class then it becomes:

    ```
    while True:
        try:
            self.number = int(input(f"{self.name}'s number: >>"))
            if self.number > 1:
                return
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print(f"{self.name}, you have to input an integer at least one!")
    ```

    Note that there is no need for the test `not isinstance(player.number, int)` because if the call to `int` succeeded then `self.number` must be an `int`.
12. The logic in `update_game_score` is quite complex. One way to simplify it would be like this:

    ```
    diff = self.player1.number - self.player2.number
    if diff < -1:
        self.player1.score += 1
    elif diff == -1:
        self.player2.score += 2
    elif diff == 0:
        print("The numbers are the same and nobody gets a point!")
    elif diff == 1:
        self.player1.score += 2
    else:
        assert diff > 1:
        self.player2.score += 1
    ```

    The reason for writing it like this is to make it easy for a reader to check that we've covered all five cases.
13. The code is now short enough that it makes sense to inline all the methods into `main` and remove the `Game` class.

#### 2. Revised code

```
GAME_WIN_POINTS = 5             # Number of points needed to win.

class Player:
    """A player in the game, with attributes:

    name: str -- The name of the player
    number: int -- Most recently input number
    score: int -- Current score

    """
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = input(f"What's the name of player {n}? >> ")
        self.score = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}: {self.score} points"

    def get_input(self):
        "Get input from the player and update player.number."
        while True:
            try:
                self.number = int(input(f"{self.name}'s number: >> "))
                if self.number > 0:
                    return
            except ValueError:
                pass
            print(f"{self.name}, you must input an integer at least one!")

def main():
    "Play the game."
    print("Welcome to the game! This game was made for two players.")
    player1, player2 = players = [Player(i) for i in (1, 2)]

    while True:
        # Get input.
        for player in players:
            player.get_input()

        # Update score.
        diff = player1.number - player2.number
        if diff < -1:
            player1.score += 1
        elif diff == -1:
            player2.score += 2
        elif diff == 0:
            print("The numbers are the same and nobody gets a point!")
        elif diff == 1:
            player1.score += 2
        else:
            assert diff > 1
            player2.score += 1

        # Display scores.
        print(f"Results: {player1} VS {player2}.")

        # Check for a winner.
        for player in players:
            if player.score >= GAME_WIN_POINTS:
                print(f"Congratulations, {player.name}! You're the winner.")
                return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```